# python 3.6 convert string to utc time zone date-time format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am getting 2 different `strings` from 2 different sources and I would like to convert these strings to common `date-time format` in `UTC timezone`. 
The 1st string value is like this : `2017-03-30T13:54:40+0300`
and the 2nd string value is like this :  `Thu Jul 6 16:57:50 2017 +0530`.
I am new to Python and Python 3.6 and it will be great if someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: @cosinepenguin: I've scanned the question you mention, and the answers, and don't see how this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem using first by converting the strings to datetime format ( the formatting was tricky part here) and later by converting the these datetimes to local time zone using astimezone function in datetime module.
Thanks everyone for the help. 
@Rohit Poudel, the link shared helped me understand date-times in python better.Can you please check if this is indeed duplicate of the mentioned link and if not , mark as non-duplicate as I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

For the ISO8601 format string (your 1st string) do this:

Install these modules (Linux assumed, and assuming you have pip installed):

```
$ pip install iso8601 pytz
```

Then in your Python console:

```
>>> import datetime, iso8601, pytz
>>> s1 = '2017-03-30T13:54:40+03:00'
>>> s1a = '2017-03-30T13:54:40.123456+03:00'    # with fraction of sec. added
>>> dt1 = iso8601.parse_date(s1)
>>> dt1
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 13, 54, 40, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), '+03:00'))
>>> dt1a = iso8601.parse_date(s1a)
>>> dt1a
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 13, 54, 40, 123456, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), '+03:00'))
```

dt1 and dt1a are instances of datetime.datetime.  They are "aware" times bearing your +03:00 timezone offset.

Now convert that into UTC times:

```
>>> dt1a.astimezone(tz=pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 10, 54, 40, 123456, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

If you wanted the results in ISO8601 format, do this:

```
>>> dt1a.astimezone(tz=pytz.utc).isoformat()
'2017-03-30T10:54:40.123456+00:00'
```

You can see that in the last line, the time is 10:54.40.123456 UTC whereas the original was 13:54:40.123456+03:00.

For your second string, convert it to instances of datetime.datetime then proceed as above.

Comment: Alternatively, without needing pytz, do this:
>>> dt1a.astimezone(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)